# Prebuilt binaries of TensorFlow for processors without AVX instruction support

Tags: tensorflow

i have just spent a day just building tensorflow from source code, but have not have any luck. Is there any prebuilt binaries for old processors available. I am runnning Windows 10(64bit) , Cuda 10 and Cudnn7.

The processor i am using is an Intel W3680 and GPU is Nvidia Gtx 1070.
I have a university project, for that i need tensorflow. Pls guide towards something...
Oh and btw i am using Anaconda.
Thanks.

Comment: There are a number of places where people are posting wheels for non-standard configs.  Look at https://github.com/yaroslavvb/tensorflow-community-wheels.  A Google search will show a bunch more.

Comment: Any luck figuring the C++ tensorflow build on windows?